# fetching id or class name of an unordered list

Tags: jquery

My Jquery console returns the below value. As you could see both `$prnt` & `$parent` return same value when compared but the if statement return false

```
 console.log($prnt)
 //ul#testin.hidden-links

 console.log($parent)
 //ul#testin.hidden-links
```

How could I access the id or class name for comparison purpose or how cd I get the below `if` statement to return value as `True`. Below is the Jquery code.

***Jquery***

```
    $(document).ready(function(){      
           $("#cbp-hrmenu > ul > li > a").on('click', function(event){
              $item = $(event.currentTarget).parent('li');
                 var $parent = ($item).parent('ul').get();
                  var $prnt = $('#cbp-hrmenu > ul').get();

                    //Below if statement doesn't work only return console 
                     //value within else statement even if if is true

                           if( $parent === $prnt){ 
                             console.log($item.index());
                               console.log("True");
                         } else {
                     console.log("false");
                  console.log($parent);
              console.log($prnt);
            }

          });
     });
```

Comment: don't use strict equality. Then try with == instead of ===

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/is/